# Label/Color Probability Plot Points by Group

Tags: matlab

I am plotting a data set consisting of the same kind of data from nominally the same source. I am using MATLAB's `probplot` command. I would like to do something along the lines of using `findgroups` to plot the points with a color corresponding to their source. I have attempted, for example,

```
probplot('lognormal', data, ~findgroups(category))
```

I am not sure how (or if) one could use the 'params' functionality to pass the `findgroups` and make this work. I'm interested in any other solutions as well.

Comment: How to do you want to differentiate locations from one another so that the colors change also accordingly?

Comment: Some point locations come from, say population A, while others come from B, and so on. I'm looking to employ something in a manner similar to gscatter in MATLAB, but grouping for the lognormal probability plot.